# Erro de mapeamento Json para Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Estou recebendo a msg abaixo, ao tentar mapear um json -- Spring Boot

> JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types

Na classe produto adicionei a informação abaixo(apesar da classe não ser Abstrata) e nao funcionou
@JsonDeserialize(as=Produto.class)

```
BufferedReader reader = Request.getReader();        
Gson gson = new Gson();     
Produto produtos =  gson.fromJson(reader, Produto.class);
```

Obs:Request é uma HttpServletRequest

Comment: Poderia botar a declaração da classe Produto também?